# How to select items from two different entries in a variant column

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with one variant column loaded with json data structured as so

```
{
    "key_a": "value_a",
    "key_b": 1,
    "key_c": "some_value",
}
{
    "key_d": "value_d",
    "key_e": 1,
}
```

And I am struggling to define a query that looks like

```
SELECT key_a, key_d FROM table WHERE key_c = 'some_value' AND key_b = key_e;
```

Where I get value_a, value_d from the return.

Is there a way to do this?

I tried doing

```
SELECT key_a, key_d FROM group_3 WITH group_1 AS ( SELECT key_a A FROM table WHERE key_c = 'some_value' ), group_2 AS ( SELECT key_d FROM table WHERE key_e = group_1.A), group_3 AS (SELECT * FROM group_1 UNION SELECT * FROM group_2)
```

But got an error that group_1.A didn't exist

Comment: what's the exact result you are looking for?

Comment: To get all the values for key_a and key_d where key_c = 'some_value' and key_e = key_b

Comment: but can you show how those results would look?

Comment: so if we have
```
{
    "key_a": "value_a",
    "key_b": 1,
    "key_c": "some-value",
}
{
    "key_d": "My group name",
    "key_e": 1,
}

I want to get value_a, My group name

Comment: Is the sample json two different rows? What would you be grouping by?

Comment: To be honest im not sure how snowflake handles it. I just load a file that follows that structure to a temporary table with one variant column. I assume each object is its own row

Comment: Yeah - I'm trying to reproduce the problem, but there's not enough information in the question to do so

Comment: Sorry Felipe, what more data do you need? The above example is excatly what I load into my snowflake

Answer (score 1):

*It seems not a valid JSON data, is that possible to change it to below JSON format and then we can achieve what you have described.*

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEST_TAB;

CREATE TABLE TEST_TAB (TEST_COL VARIANT);
INSERT INTO TEST_TAB
SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT(
    'set1', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('key_a' , 'a' , 'key_b' , 'b', 
 'key_c','c') 
    ,'set2', OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('key_d','d', 'key_e', 'e') 
);
 SELECT TEST_COL:set1:key_a,TEST_COL:set2:key_d,
 TEST_COL:set1:key_c,TEST_COL:set2:key_e
 FROM  TEST_TAB  
 WHERE TEST_COL:set1:key_c<>TEST_COL:set2:key_e;
```